# Work Visa Refusal

Tags: uk-visa, paperwork, language-test

I was denied a UK visa because the IELTS result I submitted doesn't contain a UKVI unique reference number.
I just got my NARIC Result.
I would like to know if I can still reapply for a UK work visa using my COS number. It's still a valid COS which will expire 20th of July.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
A Certificate of Sponsorship (CoS) can only be used once and will expire if it is not used by the applicant worker within 3 months of the employer assigning it to them.

Source: https://immigrationbarrister.co.uk/business-immigration/business-immigration-services/certificates-of-sponsorship/